# How to C# code (or use an app) that sends emails when exceeding allowed timeframe?

Tags: c#, timer, email-notifications

we use a custom built C# application ("communicator") to interact with several other locally installed applications (Excel, ...). The communicator gets its inputs from a queue, calls the applications in defined order (via several DLLs, again custom build) to process the inputs and submits the results to the queue. The times required to complete the steps can be predicted (step 1 (app1) completes within 10 seconds, step 2 (app2) completes within 45 seconds, etc) and the total time to process an individual order should not exceed 90 seconds.

Most of the time things run well unattended (as designed), however every now and then one of the called applications gets stuck and cannot proceed without a human interaction. This also stops the queue processing. We look into the causes and try to eliminated them - once the interruption has been detected.

We'd foremost like to reduce the time to detect the interruption - perhaps by using the communicatior or another method to detect that the expected time to complete a step has been exceeded and notify the admin of such occurence (sending an email).

Would you use the communicatior to set a timer at each step and then raise error if the expected time to complete has been exceed (and send email from within its code) or call an external application at the start of a step and its finish and let it do the timing and notifications part to avoid clogging the communicators code?

Are there some code samples you can share for timing and sending emails?
Or perhaps suggest an external application that would accepts start signals from communicator and send an email if it wouln't receive the completion message within a certain timeframe?

Best regards

Comment: I wouldn't over complicate it. You can create a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0) just before you start a specific step using your 'communicator', then when the time elapses you can use the [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=net-5.0) to send the email. There are plenty of ways to send emails though, so pick whatever you want. Just make sure to stop the timer after each step in the 'communicator' finishes.

Comment: There are so many factors that can influence processing time on a file. Where your execution of a task is only seconds, I would add a check for process time exceeding double the expected time, otherwise you may be a second or two off and send a lot of unnecessary emails.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Oakley, we'll definitely include some buffer - it's better to wait an additional minute or two than send an unnecessary email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally answered as a comment but I figure I might as well do a proper answer.

How you do this is going to depend on a lot of things. I'm simplifying because I don't know what your code actually looks like.

Here's what a basic outline of the code could look like:

```
private async Task ExecuteStepInCommunicator(TimeSpan expectedTimeToComplete)
{
    // Maybe you want to allow for some buffer as @Oakley suggested. 
    // This will give it twice as long as the expected time to complete.
    expectedTimeToComplete = expectedTimeToComplete.Add(expectedTimeToComplete);
            
    using var alertTimer = new Timer()
    {
        Interval = expectedTimeToComplete.TotalMilliseconds,
        AutoReset = false,
    };

    alertTimer.Elapsed += this.AlertTimer_Elapsed;

    // Replace the Task.Delay with your normal 'Communicator' logic
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    // Make sure the timer is stopped once your logic has finished.
    // If it hasn't run yet, no alert will be sent. If it has run this will do nothing
    alertTimer.Stop();
}

private void AlertTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Send email from here. This will be called only once, when the timer elapses. 
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=net-5.0
}
```

`System.Timer` will not block your normal code from running. Once the timer finishes, the Elapsed callback will be run on a thread from the threadpool, so it can run even when your communicator code is also running.

Because this is rather simple, I'd suggest keeping it in the same place. You suggested sending off to some other application to do the timing and notifications, but that can add a lot of complexity (and chances for things to go wrong), for little gain.

Comment: Thank you @Lolop for a complete answer. We'll look into it as suggested.